# alter composite primary key in cassandra CQL 3.0

Tags: cassandra, composite-primary-key, alter, cql3, cqlsh

I'm in a situation where I need to change the the composite primary key as follows:

**Old Primary Key: (id, source, attribute_name, updated_at);**

**New Primary Key I want: (source, id, attribute_name, updated_at);**

I issued the following (mysql like) command:

```
ALTER TABLE general_trend_table 
DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(source, id, attribute_name, updated_at);
```

I got the following error:

**Bad Request: line 1:38 no viable alternative at input 'PRIMARY'**

any idea how to get around this problem? more specifically I want to know is there any way to change the primary key in cassandra?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There is no way to change a primary key, as it defines how your data is physically stored.

You can create a new table with the new primary key, copy data from the old one, and then drop the old table.

Comment: I tried following using cqlsh, 
ALTER COLUMNFAMILY mycolumnfamily RENAME key TO key1; and this works perfectly.While trying this I got following suggestions as well. ADD,ALTER,DROP,WITH @Mikhail Can't we use these to alter primary key?

Comment: How do you rename the table?  Can you provide a full example?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a possibility to use the old primary key, you could create a materialzied view: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateMV.html
But it is only recommendable, if you would need the old key.