# Copy from Table to Table (altering Primary Key)

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, database-migration

## Context :

I need to change the order of my primarey key

```
PRIMARY KEY (a, b) --> PRIMARY KEY (b,a)
```

But in cassandra I can't just alter PRIMARY KEY like this : [alter composite primary key in cassandra CQL 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139747/alter-composite-primary-key-in-cassandra-cql-3-0)

So, I just want to move data from the old table to a new table I've created.
Since the number of rows is huge I need to use Spark.

## Data "in" :

I get the data like this from the old table:

```
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> initialRDD;
```

## Question :

Id it possible to directly save it back to the new table since the row itself didn't change?

## What I managed to do :

I could do this but it seems absurd to map from CassandraRow to CassandraRow

```
javaFunctions(initialRDD).writerBuilder("targetKeyspace", "targetTable", mapToRow(CassandraRow.class)).saveToCassandra();
```

thus it's prompting me an error :

```
Some primary key columns are missing in RDD or have not been selected: ...
```

Comment: Do you really require to do it in Java client? It should be easier to write CQL migration script.

Comment: if your data is less you can directly do it using COPY command in cql

Comment: @PatrikTřeštík  It has more than a million rows, I can not just COPY so yes I would like to do it in Java

Comment: I would still test COPY TO STDOUT piped to COPY FROM STDIN. I didn't tested it on bigger data, but piping should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use spark very much, but I think you would need to create a second table with the new key order, then load the first table into an RDD using the spark connector:

val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "table1")

Then save it to the second table with the new key order:

rdd.saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table2", SomeColumns("b", "a"))